# Run Multiple Pandas Functions Simultaneously

Tags: python, sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to execute 3 SQL queries simultaneously using Pandas.

Each of my 3 SQL queries takes 1 minute to run. Running them consecutively takes a total of 3 minutes. The queries are:

```
pd.read_sql(Query_1 , DB_Connection)
pd.read_sql(Query_2 , DB_Connection)
pd.read_sql(Query_3 , DB_Connection)
```

A workaround to reduce runtime is to open up 3 separate IPython Jupyter notebooks, place one query in each, and hit execute on all three of them at more or less the same time. Given they're running concurrently in this case, the total runtime for all 3 is 1 minute.

How can I achieve the same result of reducing total runtime to 1 minute in one IPython notebook?

---

What do you think of this potential solution using threading?

```
SQL_Queries = ["Query 1" , "Query 2" , "Query 3"]
SQL_Results = []

def myfunct(i):
    SQL_Results.append(pd.read_sql(SQL_Queries[i]))

for i in range(3):
    t = Thread(target=myfunct, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: you can use `threading` to achieve this. check out the `threading` and `multiprocessing` modules

Comment: @Mankind_008 Thanks! I've looked into threading and pasted some code in my question. Mind taking a look?